# PTP4L wrong source IP on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, ptp

When I start ptp4l as root with `ptp4l -i enp0s31f6 -m` it successfully starts and takes the grand-master role. See logs below.

However, when inspecting the packets with Wireshark, they don't originate from the IP of that interface.
Instead, they show the IP of my WiFi adapter. When I turn off WiFi, they instead use the IP of the `virbr0` from kvm.

How can I fix this?

I disabled all other network adapters. Then I see the correct IP, but that is not feasible all the time.

### What I tried

- Allowing port 319 and 320 in the firewall made PTP successfully be a leader and a follower, although the sender IP is wrong.
- apt offers linuxptp version 3.1.1, thus I compiled the latest 4.2 release from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxptp/files/) (same symptoms)
- Manually adding a route: `sudo ip route add 224.0.1.129 dev enp0s31f6`

### Logs:

```
root@host:/home/user/linuxptp# ./ptp4l -i enp0s31f6 -m
ptp4l[13393.845]: selected /dev/ptp0 as PTP clock
ptp4l[13393.845]: port 1: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[13393.845]: port 0: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
ptp4l[13401.057]: port 1: LISTENING to MASTER on ANNOUNCE_RECEIPT_TIMEOUT_EXPIRES
ptp4l[13401.057]: selected local clock e88088.fffe.257ada as best master
ptp4l[13401.057]: port 1: assuming the grand master role
```